# How can I convert for loop implementation into vectorized calculation in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I am trying to develop develop code to find cost fuction in logistic regression. I want to replce below forloop implementation with vectored iplementation.

```
  for i = 1:m_theta
        sum_gr = sum(error.*X(:,i));
        grad_temp(i) = sum_gr/(m);
    end;
```

How can I do that? Can anyone help?

Comment: what is `error` an unique value, an array ?

Comment: can you make your code compilable?

Comment: provide a complete example for us to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `error` to be a vector, you can simply use `matrix-multiplication` -

```
grad_temp = error.'*X/m
```